# Array values getting overwritten in names column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert one by one `names` in to table.
Why array values overwrite in names column just yellow insert?(replace)

**Code:**

```
<?php

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, "", $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $value=$_POST['names'];
    $colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 

    foreach ($colors as $value) {

        $query ="insert into test(names) values('$value')";
    }
    if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You are closing your `foreach()` before you execute your query.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `$query` each time round your loop and only executing the query outside the loop

Instead run your query inside the loop

```
<?php

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, "", $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Not sure why this is here??
    // as it gets overwriten in your loop    
    $value=$_POST['names'];

    $colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 

    foreach ($colors as $value) {

        $query ="insert into test(names) values('$value')";

        if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

> If you were actually using the value collected in `$value=$_POST['names'];` then your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
>
> But as you are not this is just a reminder